# why isn't the pid getting saved to the database in my typo3 extension?

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-4.5

When I save a new object the pid field in my db stays at 0, even when I use

```
$newCoupon->setPid(  $this->settings["COUPONSPID"]);
```

before the call to

```
$this->couponRepository->add($newCoupon);
```

I had previously set my repo to not respect storagepage and set my in my constants

```
plugin.tx_bpscoupons {
    ... 
    persistence {
        # cat=plugin.tx_bpscoupons//a; type=string; label=Default storage PID
        storagePid =     

    }
    ...
}
```

and that worked as expected but now I want to try using pids again for some things because there is a lib.quickstats  thing I want to use which apparently can't find records with pid=0.

I am using TYPO3 v4.5.

**Update:**

I updated the repos to remove the custom body of initializeObject(), then in my TypoScript setup I set:

```
storagePid =     {$COUPONSPID}
```

And in the TypoScript constants I set

```
COUPONSPID = 44
```

Now the objects are created on the page with the ID 44.

Comment: This reads pretty weird, why aren't you just using normal Extbase persistence settings? Respect storagePid and set it by TS?

Comment: If I understand your meaning that is what I'm doing now.  The PS section of my question refers to it, if I'm right.